# Texture map environment to simplified model

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I'd like to bake a complex scene onto a simplified object, much like when you make a skybox, or output an equirectangular image. My end goal is to bring this into Unity and have other objects moving around on the floor of this simplified object.

[image: sketch of simple environment to bake]

I'm picturing something like this, where the environment could get mapped to the cylinder, and then I just use the cylinder in Unity. The simple shape could also be a dome, too.

I originally tried outputting to an equirectangular image and then projecting that on the inside of a sphere in Unity, but items didn't look like they were really on the floor.

Is there a name for what I'm trying to do here? I think this is basically what's done with reflection maps. I'm imagining that each pixel of the cylinder's texture is colored by a ray that goes from the camera to the outer environment.

Comment: I do this about 2 years ago. I lost all data. What I remember that I found  .blend file with 6 cameras (on one place and all directions L-R,  F-B, U-D)) and  renders can be used as textures for Skycube. Second way is make cube with max reflections and bake textures. I'm not sure now, maybe secont option work only in BI.